# Prevent Account Deletion based on Child Contact Status?

Tags: apex, trigger, account, contact

I have a requirement in which when click on delete button on the account it should allow you to delete only when its related contact status is inactive.
I have written the following code which gives me list of contacts per account..

```
public class ContactsPerAccount{

    public static void contactResult()
    {
        Id accountId;
        List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>([SELECT Id, Name,Inactive__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :accountId]);
        System.debug(contacts);
        for(Contact c:Contacts){
            if(c.Inactive__c=Boolean.valueOf('true') )
            {
                System.debug('You Can not delete this account as its related contacts are Active');
            }
            else{
                System.debug('Go ahead ');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the `Account` contains any `Contact` whose `Inactive` flag is `false` it should throw an error message like

> 'You Can not delete this account as its related contacts are Active'...

In this case I have written a class here and I will use this class in trigger where I will use afterdelete event..
Can someone suggest how do I display an error message on UI after clicking on delete button..What else code do I need to modify?
is it possible to write a separate class that I written and call it in trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `SObject.addError` method. Note that you can only pass in records from the trigger context as a parameter value.

I recommend modifying your method to accept the trigger records. Best practice is to put the error message in a `Custom Label` so you can configure this user-facing copy quickly and easily. Something like:

```
public static void validateNoActiveContacts(Map<Id, Account> records)
{
    Set<Id> withActiveContact = new Map<Id>([
        SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN (
            SELECT AccountId FROM Contact
            WHERE Inactive = false
            AND AccountId IN :records.keySet()
        )
    ]).keySet();
    for (Id accountId : withActiveContact)
        records.get(accountId).addError(Label.Active_Contact_Error);
}
```

Comment: You could approach it the other way, too, if you're using Trigger.oldMap instead of Trigger.old: `for(Id accountId: accountsWithActiveContact) records.get(accountId).addError(Label.Active_Contact_Error);`

Comment: @sfdcfox Yeah I like that better. Good call.

Comment: This scenario is working fine except in one condition i.e.Merge.When I Merge 2 accounts if one of the account contain Active contacts that time my validation message is getting displayed here....If I want to bypass this validation,how can I bypass my message in this scenario?

Comment: @Dhananjay sounds like a great *new* question!

Comment: @Adrian Yeah..Trying to find out the solution but no success till now...

Comment: Anybody has any idea how can I bypass this scenario when it comes to merge two accounts?